# SUBQUERIES Invalid Identifier On Database Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to make SubQueries from some tables in Oracle Databaseand I found it that my coding is getting an error. The error info says;

**ORA-00904: "T4"."PROD_RESULT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:

*Action:
Error at Line: 7 Column: 9**

Here is my code;

```
SELECT
       T1.LINE_CD "MACHINE",
       T2.ITM_NM "ITEM NAME".
       T1.INST_NO "MANUFACTURING NO",
       T3.PROD_ST_SCHD_DT "START SCHEDULE",
       SUM(T4.PROD_RESULT)"TOTAL PRODUCTION",
       SUM(T4.PROD_RESULT)-T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY "OUTSTANDING"
  FROM ST_SASHIZU_ALL T1,
       CM_HINMO_ALL T2,
       TMCI_IM_PROD2 T3,
       (
        SELECT INST_NO, SUM(PROD_RESULT)"TOTAL PRODUCTION" 
          FROM TMCI_IM_PROD2 
         WHERE INST_NO='M190200101' 
      GROUP BY INST_NO) T4 
         WHERE 0=0
           AND T1.ITM_CD  = T2.ITM_CD
           AND T1.INST_NO = T3.INST_NO
           AND T1.INST_NO = T4.INST_NO
           AND T1.INST_NO='M190200101'
           AND T1.LINE_CD LIKE 'A%'
           AND T3.PROD_DT 
       BETWEEN TO_DATE(:qDT_FROM, 'DDMMYYYY') 
           AND TO_DATE(:qDT_TO, 'DDMMYYYY')
        HAVING SUM(T3.PROD_RESULT + 1) <= T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY 
      GROUP BY
               T1.LINE_CD,
               T2.ITM_NM,
               T1.INST_NO,
               T3.PROD_ST_SCHD_DT,
               T3.PROD_DT
      ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

I have tried to change my coding, but it did not help me. I also have tried to find other ways in google, but also I did not find it. Does anyone here could help me to rectify my problem please. Thank you

Comment: you are aliasing here - `SUM(PROD_RESULT)"TOTAL PRODUCTION"`, you are not selecting `T4.PROD_RESULT` from `TMCI_IM_PROD2`

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to select a column that you haven't got in your t4 subquery.

What you should do is use a simpler alias in the subquery, and then use that alias in your outer select, like so:

```
SELECT
       T1.LINE_CD "MACHINE",
       T2.ITM_NM "ITEM NAME".
       T1.INST_NO "MANUFACTURING NO",
       T3.PROD_ST_SCHD_DT "START SCHEDULE",
       SUM(T4.sum_prod_result) "TOTAL PRODUCTION",
       SUM(T4.sum_prod_result) - T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY "OUTSTANDING"
  FROM ST_SASHIZU_ALL T1,
       CM_HINMO_ALL T2,
       TMCI_IM_PROD2 T3,
       (
        SELECT INST_NO, SUM(PROD_RESULT) sum_prod_result
          FROM TMCI_IM_PROD2 
         WHERE INST_NO='M190200101' 
      GROUP BY INST_NO) T4 
         WHERE 0=0
           AND T1.ITM_CD  = T2.ITM_CD
           AND T1.INST_NO = T3.INST_NO
           AND T1.INST_NO = T4.INST_NO
           AND T1.INST_NO='M190200101'
           AND T1.LINE_CD LIKE 'A%'
           AND T3.PROD_DT 
       BETWEEN TO_DATE(:qDT_FROM, 'DDMMYYYY') 
           AND TO_DATE(:qDT_TO, 'DDMMYYYY')
        HAVING SUM(T3.PROD_RESULT + 1) <= T1.PROD_SCHD_QTY 
      GROUP BY
               T1.LINE_CD,
               T2.ITM_NM,
               T1.INST_NO,
               T3.PROD_ST_SCHD_DT,
               T3.PROD_DT
      ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```